LDAP: search by aliased objectClass
I've created an LDAP alias by following the FAQ:
dn: uid=alias,ou=People,dc=example,dc=net
objectclass: alias
objectclass: extensibleObject
uid: alias
aliasedobjectname: uid=target,ou=Retired People,dc=example,dc=com

The problem I'm facing is that this needs to be queried by an application (out of my control) that queries LDAP looking for a particular objectClass, like this:
(&(objectClass=person)(uid=alias))

This query misses the alias, I guess because the alias object has just "alias" and "extensibleObject" as classes... Is this expected? Is there a way to work around this, server-side? I mean, to tell the LDAP server to look for "aliased" properties?
(I'm using slapd 2.4.57)

Alias dereferencing is normally done server-side, but is client opt-in during the search operation; there is no server-side setting to activate it by force when the client asks for "deref=0".
If you're using the ldapsearch tool, specify the -a option to choose whether you want the server to dereference aliases during attribute comparison (search), during base DN lookup (find), or both (always).
Search options:
  -a deref   one of never (default), always, search, or find

Note that dereferencing is all-or-nothing; if enabled, then the filter will only match against the target entry, not against the alias. Any extra attributes therefore need to be added to the original entry (e.g. if it is aliased under a different 'uid', then the target will need to have both 'uid' values).
Within libldap, dereferencing is configured as a global (connection level) option OPT_DEREF which defaults to 0. If you cannot modify the application, but it uses libldap, then there's a chance it will honor DEREF always in ldap.conf(5) or the LDAPDEREF=always environment variable.
In other LDAP clients it's usually a parameter to the search() function. If you cannot modify the application and it uses a different LDAP client library, then you'll need to find (or write) a slapd overlay that can achieve something similar – or some kind of LDAP proxy that forces the 'deref' parameter during each search operation.
There is a built-in overlay for referral chasing, but I could not find one for controlling alias behavior. It might be possible to use slapo-rwm(5) to trick the program into seeing the right entry (though I doubt it), or do something using a modification to slapo-translucent(5) or a similar patch to slapd-ldap(5) so that they would provide a "proxy" server that always requests alias dereferencing when forwarding requests to your real LDAP backend server.

Testing with ldapsearch, querying for just (uid=alias) works when I use -a never or -a find, but it never works when I add the objectClass part :/ Nothing gets returned

Yes, because you want -a search or -a always according to what you've described. The 'search' deref mode enables "looking for aliased properties" during search filter processing, while the 'find' deref mode is only for direct lookup by DN.

If I use search or always with (&(objectClass=person)(uid=alias)) I get no results :/ The application looks for the "aliasing" name but with the "aliased" objectClass

Are the two uid attributes different? If so I don't think it is going to work – either the entry is fully dereferenced, or not dereferenced at all. (Well, it would work if you added uid: alias to the target entry – i.e. a second uid attribute – but for posixAccount entries that might not be a good idea, though definitely possible.)

Yes they are different, and yes if I add a second uid to the target ldapsearch works... I'll try to work with this, thanks :)
